# SSRS Execution Log updating problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

[image: Error]

Hi All,
When i tried to execute RSExecutionLog_Update.dtsx to update my execution log data. it throws me this error. Can anyone help with this issue with me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line: `Invalid object name "ExecutionLog"`

Could be that the table (or database) hasn't been created, or there's a permissions problem.

You haven't posted any information on the tables you are using or actual step that failed. You will be able to see in the SSIS package exactly which step failed and look for more detail.